# Evaluate $\int\int_SF.dS$ where $F=(xz,yz,x^2+y^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate $\int\int_SF.dS$ where $F=(xz,yz,x^2+y^2)$

Where $S$ is the closed surface obtained from the surfaces $x^2+y^2\leq 4,z=2,x^2+y^2\leq 16,z=0$ on the top and the bottom and $z=4-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ on the side.

How we can solve such integrals?I need your help.

**Edit:** without using the Gauss Divergence theorem.

Comment: It depends, what is the surface?

Comment: Those sets you describe aren't all surfaces, the first and third are solids.

Comment: @AdamHughes No this surface is like a lamp.

Comment: @AdamHughes $x^2+y^2\leq 4,z=2$ is a disk,$x^2+y^2\leq 16,z=0$ is also a disk and $z=4-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is a cone.So it is like a lamp bounded by these three.

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: @MarkFantini sorry I will take care for the next time.

Comment: @user163993 oh, you should specify which equations go with which other equations:  all you use are commas, so it's hard to tell.